# How to get PID from within bash shell script

Tags: bash, process, docker

I have the following code that submits several subjobs withing a docker container:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "all files of a given type"; do 
     docker exec -itd "docker container" "command to be executed within docker container" &
done

pidlist=$(pgrep -f "command to be executed within docker container")

for pid in $pidlist; do
    echo $pid
    wait $pid
done
```

My goal is to have the script wait to exit until all the subjobs are done. I need this since this script is part of a larger script containing other commands and scripts.

However, the PIDs that I get are not the same as when I use top at the terminal to locate the subjobs and so, the script exits after it has submitted all the subjobs.

Comment: You're forking twice: with `-d` and with `&`. Also I'm not sure it's a good idea to use the option `-t` (and  keeping `-i` would require something else than the terminal as input too).

Comment: thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wait on explicit pids; if all your script is doing is tarting a number of background processes, you can just wait for them all to complete. Try something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for file in "all files of a given type"; do 
    docker exec -itd "docker container" "command to be executed within docker container" &
done

wait
```

This modified version of your script starts some number of background processes, then waits for all of them to terminate.

Comment: Doesn't a single ``wait`` wait for all children?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' doh -- my mistake, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the info